# Stop UIImageView from being touched more than once

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I'm new to swift and am creating a tic tac toe game, I have most of the functionality working at the moment but haven't been able to work out how to stop a square from being touched more than once. The below code is how I have recognised the touches so far.

Comment: you can use tag on your image, if it's a UIImageView. Tag it 0 untouched, 1 touched, and check against the tag.

Comment: Sorry Euguene, not sure how I would prevent that UIImageView from being touched again by using a tag?

Comment: when you touch it first, you make tag = 1, when you touch it second time, you check if tag is 1, if it is you skip this touch. If I understand what you're doing correctly, this should do the trick.

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin what an ugly workaround! please don't use view tags for such purposes

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin I've tried topleft.isUserInteractionEnabled = false for example, but thats not working for me. I don't quiet understand how I would be able to skip that UIImageView in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

Usually with iOS you let them do the work for you. In your case, I'd use the `UIButton` class and put tap-actions on them.

So, simply open your storyboard and replace your `UIImageView` objects with `UIButton` objects. Then set the image to whatever you start with (from your code I guess it's something like `Picture1.png`) on the right hand in the field marked in the screenshot.

[image: button - image - attribute]

Repeat for all nine TicTacToe buttons.

Ctrl-Track from the first button into your control view and set the action. The action window should look like this:

[image: button action to be reused]

This should add a function to your control view class, like:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // All your game response goes here
}
```

where `sender` is the button, that was actually pressed.

Now ctrl-track all other buttons onto this same function. The function is then called, no matter which button was pressed. Use `sender` to set the right image on the right button.

You can now fill the function with all your code. I would except some representation of the game status - e.g. a 2dim array - that keeps which user did click which field and can be used to check, if one user did win.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jboi, but I have been told that for this project I have to use UIImageView's

Comment: In this case you can go either of two ways:
(1) who ever sticks on ImageViews might have not all insides to decide properly. Let's find out and discuss (that would be my way, but I'm old and heavily experienced in going this way)
And (2) way is to use one intermediate step on storyboard: Add a `TapRecognizer` to each ImageView and ctrl-track the action from them to your function in the view controller. The rest stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply add a flag?

```
var isTouched = false
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let Touch = event?.allTouches!.first!

    if topleft.frame.contains((Touch?.location(in: self.view))!) && !self.isTouched{
    self.isTouched = true
        if currentPlayer == 1 {
            topleft.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Picture2.png")
            currentPlayer = 2
            playerturn.text = "Player 2, it's your turn!"
            playerturn.textAlignment = .center
        }
        else {
            topleft.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Picture3.png")
            currentPlayer = 1
            playerturn.text = "Player 1, it's your turn!"
            playerturn.textAlignment = .center
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work either Federico. I was still able to click on the top left square multiple times.